# Inserir só a linha preenchida em php

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho este código:

```
<?php

$j=0;

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {


$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" size="45" name= "NomeUtente[]" id= "NomeUtente" value="'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" size="1" name= "Quarto[]" id= "Quarto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Quarto'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="datetime" name= "DataRegisto[]" id= "DataRegisto" value="'. date("Y-m-d H:i:s") .'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Miccao['.$j.']"> Realizado <input type="text" name= "Tipo1[]" id= "Tipo1" size="30" ></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Dejeccao['.$j.']"> Realizado <input type="text" name= "Tipo[]" id= "Tipo" size="30" ></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <select name="Colaborador[]" id="Colaborador">
   <option value="xxxxxxxxxxxx">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</option>
</select></td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 

$j++;
    }

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';



echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
echo $tabela1;   

echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registo'>";

echo "</form>";

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

?>
```

Para inserir tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{
$NomeUtente = $_POST['NomeUtente'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["NomeUtente"]);$i++) { 
$utente = $_POST['NomeUtente'][$i]; 
$quarto = $_POST['Quarto'][$i]; 
$data = $_POST['DataRegisto'][$i]; 
$miccao = $_POST['Miccao'][$i]; 
$tipo1 = $_POST['Tipo1'][$i]; 
$dejeccao = $_POST['Dejeccao'][$i]; 
$tipo = $_POST['Tipo'][$i]; 
$colaborador = $_POST['Colaborador'][$i]; 

$miccao = $miccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : ""; 
$dejeccao = $dejeccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : ""; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Tipo1, Dejeccao, Tipo, Colaborador) VALUES ('$utente', '$quarto', '$data', '$hora', '$miccao', '$tipo1', '$dejeccao', '$tipo', '$colaborador')"; 
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 

}
}
?>
```

Agora só devia inserir na tabela as linhas em que seleciono uma ou as duas checkboxes, mas assim está a inserir as linhas todas quando faço registar na tabela da base de dados. Estava a funcionar bem, enquanto não mostrava o valor no campo DataRegisto

Esta foi a alteração que realizei e deixou de funcionar:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="datetime-local" name= "DataRegisto[]" id= "DataRegisto" ></td>';
```

para

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="datetime" name= "DataRegisto[]" id= "DataRegisto" value="'. date("Y-m-d H:i:s") .'"></td>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com essa parte do código:

```
$miccao = $miccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : "";
$dejeccao = $dejeccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : "";
```

Você pode envolver a linha que faz o INSERT no banco com um `if` verificando se uma das variáveis não está vazia. Ficaria assim:

```
if( $miccao != "" || $dejeccao != "" ){
 // linha do INSERT
}
```

Aplicando ao código:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{
$NomeUtente = $_POST['NomeUtente'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["NomeUtente"]);$i++) { 
$utente = $_POST['NomeUtente'][$i]; 
$quarto = $_POST['Quarto'][$i]; 
$data = $_POST['DataRegisto'][$i]; 
$miccao = $_POST['Miccao'][$i]; 
$tipo1 = $_POST['Tipo1'][$i]; 
$dejeccao = $_POST['Dejeccao'][$i]; 
$tipo = $_POST['Tipo'][$i]; 
$colaborador = $_POST['Colaborador'][$i]; 

$miccao = $miccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : ""; 
$dejeccao = $dejeccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : ""; 

if( $miccao != "" || $dejeccao != "" ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Tipo1, Dejeccao, Tipo, Colaborador) VALUES ('$utente', '$quarto', '$data', '$hora', '$miccao', '$tipo1', '$dejeccao', '$tipo', '$colaborador')"; 
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

}
}
?>
```

Comment: verdade... Era mais simples do que eu propus. kkkk

Answer (score 2):

Tente fazer assim:

```
... código anterior ...

$utente = $_POST['NomeUtente'][$i]; 
$quarto = $_POST['Quarto'][$i]; 
$data = $_POST['DataRegisto'][$i]; 
$miccao = isset($_POST['Miccao'][$i]) ? $_POST['Miccao'][$i] : false; // verfica se está marcado
$tipo1 = $_POST['Tipo1'][$i]; 
$dejeccao = isset($_POST['Dejeccao'][$i]) ? $_POST['Dejeccao'][$i] : false; // verifica se está marcado
$tipo = $_POST['Tipo'][$i]; 
$colaborador = $_POST['Colaborador'][$i]; 

if($dejeccao !== false || $miccao !== false){ // aqui está o pulo do gato 
    // se dejeccao estiver marcado OU miccao estiver marcado ...

    $miccao = $miccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : ""; 
    $dejeccao = $dejeccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : ""; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Tipo1, Dejeccao, Tipo, Colaborador) VALUES ('$utente', '$quarto', '$data', '$hora', '$miccao', '$tipo1', '$dejeccao', '$tipo', '$colaborador')"; 
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
}

... código posterior ...
```

Desta forma ele irá inserir APENAS os registros com checkbox marcados.